# how to select a particular tab from other page using anchor tag in JQuery..?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, anchor

I wonder if we can able to select a particular tab in a JQuery tab system from another page..?

For example I have a 4 menus that is Home | About | Services | Contact
In services page I have a tab system with 5 tabs(Flight, Hotels, International Flight, Rail, Bus) in it, so I'm coming to the point is one who select Bus link from the home page I need to display the Bus tab(default visible one is Flight) in services page.

I have tried to give the bus link in home page like this..
services.php#tab4 (like anchor tag method)

unfortunately it doesn't work..

Im using the following JQuery for my tab system..

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //When page loads...
    $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
    $("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active_pr").show(); //Activate first tab
    $(".tab_content:first").show(); //Show first tab content

    //On Click Event
    $("ul.tabs li").click(function() {

        $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
        $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
        $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content

        var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the href attribute value to identify the active tab + content
        $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active ID content
        return false;
    });

});
```

tab links in services pages given in ul li like below

```
<ul class="tabs">
        <li><a href="#tab1">Flight</li>
        <li><a href="#tab2">Hotels</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab3">International Flight</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab4">Rail</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab5">Bus</a></li>
</ul>
```

I hope that someone can answer the above question.

Thanks

Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be the complete implementation given your new request:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var strHash = document.location.hash;

    if (strHash == "") {

        // Go to the first tab as long as there's no other tab specified on which
        // to start.

        $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
        $("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active_pr").show(); //Activate first tab
        $(".tab_content:first").show(); //Show first tab content

    } else
        $("a[href='" + strHash + "']").parent().click();

    //On Click Event
    $("ul.tabs li").click(function() {

        $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
        $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
        $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content

        var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the href attribute value to identify the active tab + content
        $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active ID content
        return false;

    });

});
```

The issue was that you were not considering that if there was a tab specified to go to (the document's hash), you still had that "//When page loads..." area running regardless.  You could even shorten the first conditional's contents from:

```
    $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
    $("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active_pr").show(); //Activate first tab
    $(".tab_content:first").show(); //Show first tab content
```

to:

```
    $("ul.tabs li:first").click();
```

... considering you already have the same basic functionality delineated in the later click event, but that's up to you.  Also, you're welcome!

Comment: Gabriel, this is awesome! I think I can set up the other things somehow, really appreciate your help.

Comment: What do you mean?  What other things?  And, once again, you're welcome -- anytime!

Answer (score 1):

Before or after your click() definition, add this:

```
strHash = document.location.hash;

if (strHash != "")
    $("a[href='"+strHash+"']").parent().click();
```

Comment: Thank you Gabriel for the quick replay, I'm sorry that I didn't understand the above one you gave, could you be more specific how to implement you code..?

Comment: I was suggesting you add this code inside your $(document).ready( ... ) area.  Give it a shot and let me know.  It would help to have the URL of this page.

Comment: Gabriel, can I ask you one thing, its working fine now I click the four links from other pages its directly go to the services page but the default first tab is showing for a moment then loading the clicked tab.. Do we can directly go(show) to the clicked tab from other page without showing the defualt tab in services page?

Answer (score 0):

([I've made a 'fiddle' on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5c72z/) so you can test this answer.)

You code was almost correct; it seems that a few HTML errors may have been the cause. Assuming our HTML looks like:

```
<ul id="tabs">
        <li><a href="#tab1">Flight</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2">Hotels</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab3">International Flight</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab4">Rail</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab5">Bus</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tab1" class="tab_content">1</div>
<div id="tab2" class="tab_content">2</div>
<div id="tab3" class="tab_content">3</div>
<div id="tab4" class="tab_content">4</div>
<div id="tab5" class="tab_content">5</div>
```

... our JavaScript should be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //When page loads, hide all content 
    $(".tab_content").hide();
    $(".tab_content:first").show(); //Show first tab content
    $("#tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
    //On Click Event
    $("#tabs a").click(function() {

        //Remove any "active" class
        $("#tabs .active").removeClass("active");

        //Add "active" class to selected tab
        $(this).parent().addClass("active");

        // Hide all tab content
        $(".tab_content").hide();

        //Find the href attribute value to identify the active tab + content
        var a = $(this).attr("href");

        //Fade in the active ID content
        $(a).fadeIn();

        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for the descriptive answer, but this is not what I'm looking for although my tab system is working fine, I want to show/display a particular tab in the services page from another page(where the link is, for example in home page) when someone made a click..