# How to redirect an user from one tab to another tab of other page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Basically there are 2 pages with me :-

Index page

```
   <div class="box-footer text-center">
   <a href="~/Groups/MyGroups.html#sent" class="uppercase" id="viewGrp">View my Groups</a>
  </div>
```

MyGroups.html

```
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs pull-right ui-sortable-handle">
      <li class=""><a id="clickSearch" data-toggle="tab" href="#search" aria-expanded="false">Search</a></li>
     <li class=""><a data-toggle="tab" href="#sent" aria-expanded="false">My Groups</a></li>
     <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#all" aria-expanded="true">All Groups</a></li>
    <li class="pull-left header"><i class="fa fa-inbox"></i> Groups</li>
 </ul>
<div id="sent" class=" tab-pane">
         //some content  
 </div>
```

Now how can user be redirected from HTML page 1 on clicking " View my groups" to the `#sent` div on another Html page ?

Things seacrhed :- Using `jquery .click()` function

But Need proper guidance in syntax .

Had a look on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8250426/how-to-select-a-particular-tab-from-other-page-using-anchor-tag-in-jquery) , got the basic idea but still not able to achieve what's needed .

Answer (score 4):

You can link directly from the href of the first page

`<a href="page2.html#sent" class="uppercase" id="viewGrp">View my Groups</a>`

adding the `#sent` to the link will automatically scroll to the appropriate `div`

Comment: tried that , simplest way ... but its not working :(